# How to install unetbootin

Tags: command-line

I do not have internet at home so I've downoaded a unetbootin bin file off of techspot.com to my android phone to transfer and install on my Linux computer. I'm trying to figure out how in the heck I'd go about installing this using the command line once i have it tranfered to the computer. Any ideas please? I need this to try and create a usb bootable stick to fix another computer i have and i dont know what else to do or how to go about accomplishing this task

I am not sure what to try in order to install this

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Do you already have an iso of Ubuntu(?) and want to install it onto a usb key?

Comment: I am running ubuntu 16.04.5 on the computer im trying to figure out how to install the unetbootin on

Comment: You need find and down load the .deb file, which is the binary file package that is install able in Ubuntu.  you can get it from here. https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html

Comment: Will that work for me?? Im new to ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Use Startup Disk Creator instead of UNetbootin. It's already installed. See full instructions on the official site: [Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Comment: The user was asking about how to use a software product that was not Ubuntu installer. Hence the 'Startup Disk Creator' is not helpful in creating bootable devices that are not Ubuntu installer media.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the .bin file, just run it. Per the [official site](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html):

> To run these binaries, download them and run the command `chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux`, or go to Properties->Permissions and check "Execute"), then start the application by running `./unetbootin-linux`

Although you'll need to replace `unetbootin-linux` with the actual filename - either `unetbootin-linux64-661.bin` for 64-bit or `unetbootin-linux-661.bin` for 32-bit.

---

If you want to install UNetbootin, you can download the .deb file from the [Packages](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) page of gezakovacs's PPA.